# Factory Girl: Reuse association as attribute

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I have a model `Plan` that has a `Creator` and a `Contact`. Contacts belong to creators. Each `Plan`'s `contact` **must belong to the `creator`**.

How can I use FactoryGirl to ensure that the `contact` association is coming from the `creator.contacts` array?

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    name "MyString"
    user
    contact {user.contacts.sample}
end
```

This, however, does not work. Any ideas?

Note that I have a validation on the `Plan` model that ensures the contact assigned belongs to the creator. This currently fails this validation.

Comment: How excactly does the validation fail? What gets printed if you do `contact { p(user.contacts.sample) }` ?

Comment: It's nil. I needed a reload call on the user. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a `reload` call on the user, since the user factory creates contacts in an after create callback.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to build cumbersome object with dependencies:

1. Use FactoryGirl [callbacks](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks). In your case you should define `after(:create)` callback and assign additional dependencies.
2. Create helper method which will create your object and assign additional dependencies. This way similar to first but it more flexible.